# how can i put the table on the right side on the screen?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to put the table on the right upside in space
but I don t know where to add code.
I've not been so long since I studied php.
Here is the code related to the table under the map.

```
<div id="info_table" style="width: 700px; height: 130px;background:#356884;">
    <table border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><center>lat</center></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="xPoint" id="xPoint" size="20" /><td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><center>lg</center></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="yPoint" id="yPoint" size="20" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: <div id="info_table" style="width: 700px; height: 130px;background:#356884; float:right;">

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP, it's a styling-question - so it's CSS.

Comment: how is the map positioned?

Comment: `<center>` has been deprecated and should no longer be used. I'm surprised they're still teaching that.

Comment: thanky guys. i already used float: right but that's not exatly what i want. i want put the table right up side..

Answer (score 1):

Could do it with flexbox and add some media-queries

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
#map {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
#info_table {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div id="map">


  </div>
  <div id="info_table" style="height: 130px;background:#356884;">
    <table border="1">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <center>lat</center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="xPoint" id="xPoint" size="20" />
            <td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <center>lg</center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="yPoint" id="yPoint" size="20" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

add css float property  to your main div

```
<div id="info_table" style=" float:right!important;">
```

Comment: **This is really a comment, not an answer.**  I appreciate that you may not yet have sufficient reputation to leave comments but please do not use the answer system as a replacement. Gaining reputation is fairly easy and only requires a little effort on your part. Thanks!

Comment: please do not poison your code by using `important`

Comment: thanky guys. i already used float: right but that's not exatly what i want. i want put the table right up side..